# Need to reset PinchZoom.js plugin after a click

Tags: jquery-plugins

creating a mobile website using PinchZoom.js plugin to zoom in and zoom out on a map. It also has a search feature that highlights areas on the map.

When the map is zoomed in, and someone searches, I want pinchzoom.js to reset back to the zoomed out view. I can achieve this by removing the style on the Zoom Container through jquery. but when I tap back on the map, it starts zooming from the original zoomed in location, before the search.

How would I go about resetting the pinchzoom.js plugin back to its original onload scale from a jQuery click function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $(function reset() {
       $('div.pinch-zoom').each(function () {
          new RTP.PinchZoom($(this), {
                maxZoom: 10
          });
       });
    })
 });

</script>

<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#contactlink').click(function(){
       $('#formbox').slideToggle('fast');

       $('.pinch-zoom .activeLocation').removeClass('activeLocation');
     });
 });
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#formbox').click(function(){
         $('#formbox').slideToggle('fast');
      });
   });
})
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
    jQuery('#E1').click(function() {
       jQuery('.pinch-zoom').empty();
       jQuery('.E1').addClass("activeLocation");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to reset zoom image.So save old image src of zoom image in one variable and create new html element i.e. image with same id and set old image src which we saved in temporary variable.With orientation change we can use same solution.

In your case save your value of zoom element and delete it and recreate html element and assign old value.

May be it is not proper solution.But it works for me.